# How to pass properties between parent and child classes?

Tags: php

Ok, I know there are similar questions, but they don't quite answer my question. I have a rather long class and decided to break it up. The bulk of it is a set of functions determining whether or not to change a certain value (both in the parent class and the database). The issue I'm having is inheritance and I'm clearly not understanding.

The problem is that the properties in the parent class aren't determined until after certain functions have executed. I need those properties in the child class in order to update the properties in the parent class once the child has finished doing its thing. Because of this, a simple "new Child" won't work (or will it?), because the properties haven't been determined in the new parent created.

I'm trying NOT to instantiate another instance of the parent class in order to repopulate the properties again. But at the same time, I don't need to always instantiate the child class when the parent is instantiated.

Here's what I'm trying to do...

```
class parentClass 
{
    public $value1;
    public $value2;
    public $value3;

    public function getValues()
    {
        $this->curValues();

        $chi = new childClass();

        $chi->updValues();

        echo var_dump($this->value1, $this->value2, $this->value3);
    }

    public function curValues()
    {
        $this->value1 = 'first value';
        $this->value2 = 'second value';
    }
}

class childClass extends parentClass
{
    public function updValues()
    {
        if (2 > 1) {
            $this->value2 = 'blue value';
            $this->value3 = 'third value';
        }
    }
}

$hmm = new ParentClass();

$hmm->getValues();
```

The output is

```
first value
second value
```

The intended output is

```
first value
blue value
third value
```

I feel like I'm overlooking something painfully simple. How can I achieve this? Or is my thought process completely left field?

Comment: You are creating a childClass object inside one of the methods of the parentClass -- it has no effect on inheritance, because it is a separate object, and not related to `$this`.

Comment: Yes, I'm realizing... I'm thinking of forgoing extending the classes altogether and making the "child" a separate class that the "parent" gets passed to.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call a child's method from its parent, but you *can* call a parent method from a child.

Depending on what final outcome you are trying to achieve, you might try overriding one of the parent methods in the child class. For example:

```
class childClass extends parentClass
{
    public function curValues()
    {
        $this->value1 = 'first value';
        if (2 > 1) {
            $this->value2 = 'blue value';
            $this->value3 = 'third value';
        }
    }
}
```

And then create an instance of the child class instead of the parent class:

```
$hmm = new childClass();
$hmm->getValues();
```

Comment: Yeah, I was considering that method, however, the overall function will have a few children and maybe grandchildren, which just complicates the matter. Honestly, I think I'm overthinking it. Although I'm still playing with it, it might be easiest to simply pass the entire parent to the child as a variable.

Comment: If you are passing one object to another as a parameter, you may not need to make it a parent/child relationship at all.

Comment: Exactly my current thinking! Trying to get it to work as I type.